# Corrupt iPhone App Name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I've done an adhoc build to test an application, but when I drag it into iTunes to add to my devices it is getting a corrupt name.  It comes up with the name

"*Myapp Name <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//APPLE//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">*" which continues with the whole plist

I've tried the obvious, clean/rebuild/reboot.  This worked fine last time I worked on the app and I've done nothing to project settings other than incement the version number and a couple of minor code changes.  I've since update XCode to 3.2.1 and iTunes to 9.0.3.

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: What does your info.plist looks like?

Comment: @Diederik Hoogenboom: Cheers, I had a look in the source and for some reason the bundle name had a copy of the rest of the (original) plist file embedded in it, no idea how that happened.  If you add an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine your info.plist is malformed. It appears as though another plist has been added as an attribute of one of the keys (most likely your app name key).